# Finding Roots of simple high level polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have a polynomial $67x^{12}-2400x^1-67 = 0$

Is there a way to find this equations real (preferably rational) roots >0 by hand, without a calculator?

When I entered this equation into an online graphical calculator it showed me two roots. one at around -0.028 and one around 1.39 , though it wouldn't tell me the exact values. Is this because it is approximating the roots or is there a way to find the roots?

Comment: It is approximating them using a programmatic approach. There is no general formula above degree 4; there is the well known quadratic equation $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$, a more complex cubic equation, and even a (very long) quartic equation, but beyond that, there is no general exact form. Technically every polynomial will have algebraic roots (because that's the definition of algebraic) but there's no general solution and for this problem I don't see how one would approach it. I highly doubt there are any rational roots as you asked for though.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [rational roots theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)?  This only gives six rational numbers to try...

Comment: Did you shift the decimal wrong in the negative answer? I got left side negative at $-.027$ and positive at $-.028.$

Comment: @Moo In the post it gives $-0.28$ and my calculations say it should be between $-.028$ and $-.027,$ in agreement with the several digit negative answer in your comment. The value in the post is off by a factor of 10.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes my bad it's approximately -0.028 I incorrectly transcribed from the graph.

Comment: @EricTowers I haven't heard of the rational roots theorem before, but it sounds promising. I'll try it. Thank you.

Comment: There is no closed form for the roots, but the negative real root is within $\,10^{-20}\,$ of $\,- \frac{67}{2400}\,$, just because $\,x^{12}\,$ becomes negligible for small $\,x\,$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that, in the real domain, you want to solve for $x$ the equation
$$67x^{12}-2400x=67$$ which does not present any difficulty using numerical method.

If $k=0$, the problem is simple and the solutions are $x_1=0$ and $x_2=\left(\frac{2400}{67}\right)^{1/11}$.

Now, for an approximation, let $x=x_1+\epsilon$ and use the binomial theorem limited to its first term. So, ignoring the higher order terms, we have, *as an approximation*,
$$-67-2400 \epsilon+O\left(\epsilon^2\right)=0 \implies x=-\frac{67}{2400}=-0.0279167$$ For the large root,we shall have
$$-67+26400\left(x-\left(\frac{2400}{67}\right)^{1/11}\right)+ O(...)=0$$ and then, *as an approximation*,
$$x=\left(\frac{2400}{67}\right)^{1/11}+\frac{67}{26400}=1.38701$$ while the solutions are $x=-0.0279167$ (!!) and $x=1.38699$.

**Done with my phone !**